# My Kindle 4 is no longer recognized: how can I get it to work again?

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, kindle

when my Kindle was connected to my Ubuntu laptop it suddenly rebooted..
all the documents are gone and it is no longer recognized by Ubuntu.

I have reformatted the partition (fat32) using gparted, but it still is not recognized.

What steps could I take to make it work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way that worked for me.

I formatted my Kindle (partition in /dev/sdc1) using

```
sudo mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/sdc1
```

which made Ubuntu recognize it again as a generic USB device.

This was not enough though, because the files I was copying it were not present in my Kindle then.

I ejected it from my computer and, while keeping it attached to the USB. I performed a factory reset (you can do it from Kindle settings menu). [note: I had tried a factory reset alone before formatting it using mkdosfs but it didn't work as well]

When it finished it, I tried to unplug and plug the USB and it started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Open up Terminal and try this:

```
    sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

I encountered a very similar problem with another device and this allowed me to mount it to my Ubuntu system.

Comment: I had already tried this, it doesn't work for me.